# Collect and display objects belonging to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am hoping to create a link on a User show page that will, when clicked, show a collection of the Pics the user has posted. I'm not sure if I'm going the right direction with this.

user_controller.rb (just what need)

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_collection = Pic.all.collect { |a| a.user_id }
  end
```

show.html.erb (again, just the important part)

```
Pics Posted: <%= link_to @user.pics.count, @users_collection %>
```

Of course, it fails on the User Show page. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you're built your models, there could be many ways to do it. Does your `pic` model have `user_id` column in it? In that case you could get all pics from one user simply by:

First in controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @pics = Pic.where(user_id: @user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end

def show_pics
  @user = User.find(params[:user_params])
  @pics = Pic.where(user_id: @user.id)
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to :controller => "users", :action => 'show_pics' , :user_params => @user.id, :remote => true do %>
  <%= @pics.count %>
<% end %>
<div id="ajax-pics"></div>
```

Then in **views/users** create **users/_pics.html.erb**

```
<% @pics.each do |pic| %>
  <%= pic %>
<% end %>
```

And then in **views/users** create **users/show_pics.js.erb**

```
$("#ajax-pics").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/pics')) %>");
```

And finally in routes.rb

```
get "/show_pics" => "users#show_pics"
```

**//Edit:** Oh dear, you need a link? Then you'll need some AJAX. Wait a sec I'll update my answer.

**//Edit 2:** That should do it.

Comment: I didn't even think about creating a partial. Now... I'm getting an error: No route matches {:action=>"show_pics", :controller=>"users", :id=>"1", :user_params=>1}. Do I need to update my routes to add a :colllection?